# Chrome extension not loading injected scripts with "charset" in MIME type

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, character-encoding, google-chrome-extension, mime-types

I have been attempting to work out why an injected content script in my Chrome Extension (unpackaged) would not load with a `charset` parameter in the MIME type (tested using Chrome 28.0.1500.95 stable):

```
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = chrome.extension.getURL("myscript.js");
script.type = 'application/ecmascript;charset=UTF-8';
script.async = false;
script.onload = function () { this.parentNode.removeChild(this); };
head.appendChild(script);
```

When the `;charset=UTF-8` portion of the code is removed, the script loads normally.  However, when that section is included (which *appears* to be a valid MIME type parameter), the script is loaded to the DOM, but never executed.  Does anyone know why this would be the case?  Note that the included file is encoded using UTF-8 (no BOM, checked using a hex editor).

EDIT: to clarify, I want to know why it seems that `charset` parameter doesn't work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was based on a misunderstanding of the specification. When the specification asks not to include the charset, it means that you must not include the `;charset=abc` bit, not that the HTML charset attribute cannot be specified.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is how you specify `charset`. I.e. although it may be a valid addition to the `type`, the browser may only automatically run `text/javascript` and `application/ecmascript` exclusively. I don't know, but try this;

```js
script.type = 'application/ecmascript';
script.charset = 'UTF-8';
```

Comment: well, if it didn't work (did you try it?) try not specifying a type at all, because as your link states it reverts to 'text/javascript' anyway

Comment: Not omit the `charset`, omit the `type`. I thought you wanted to *specify* a `charset` and still have it run. Curious, have you tested Firefox? May be just chrome